# Google Charts: Line Chart with multiple vAxis and Checkbox to add and remove values

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I would like to make something like the Graph in Google Adnsese, where you can add more values in the chart and compare them in one graph. Has anyone some simple example of this with google charts and expecially the line chart?

I would like to have 3-4 checkboxes with different values and add or remove them from the chart by check or uncheck the checkbox of each value.